# Why are packages not installing to both versions of Python on my Mac (in /User/name/Library and /usr/local/bin)?

Tags: python

I have been trying to install `tensorflow` and I keep getting this error that the module `six` is not found.

```
$ python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/name/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import six as _six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```

However when I try to install `six`, it says Requirement already satisfied.

```
$ sudo pip3 install six
Password:
WARNING: The directory '/Users/name/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.15.0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE/EDIT:
Thank you all for your answers. I ended up using `pyenv global 3.7.4` and that fixed all my problems. I'm not really sure why, but I'm sure that I'll understand better as I continue reading about and using Python.

Comment: Well, it says to try using `sudo`'s `-H` flag, so run `sudo -H pip3 install six`. You also don't need to use `sudo`, if you omit `sudo` it would just install only for your user. However, omitting `sudo` used to solve many of my pip problems, so try that.

Comment: Which command did you use to install tensorflow?

Comment: I used ```pip3 install tensorflow```. Everything ended up working after using ```pyenv global 3.7.4```.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstall the package, that solved a couple of issues in my environment..

```
pip3 uninstall six
pip3 install six
```